Why does my simple C++ program with shared_ptr segfault?
Why does the following simple C++ program with shared_ptr segfault?
Is it because block should not be initialized with std::make_shared<char[]>(BLOCKSIZE)?
If I use a unique_ptr there's no issue.
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#define BLOCKSIZE 100000

struct MyClass {
    std::shared_ptr<char[]> block;

    MyClass() : block(std::make_shared<char[]>(BLOCKSIZE)) {}

    void fill_block() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < BLOCKSIZE; ++i) {
            block[i] = static_cast<char>(i % 99);
        }
    }

    void print_one(size_t i) {
        if (i < BLOCKSIZE) {
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(block[i]);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Index out of range!";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        MyClass x;
        x.fill_block();
        x.print_one(i);
    }

  return 0;
}

I run this with:
g++ shared_ptr_test.cpp -o shared_ptr_test
./shared_ptr_test
Segmentation fault


What compiler and version? What compile flags? No issues here with gcc and clang. https://godbolt.org/z/95dE3fjK7

g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0

Also, if you compile on godbolt with C++17 it throws a compilation error.

@user24714692: I'm not asking how to optimize the program, I'm asking why it segfaults.

https://godbolt.org/z/qjh1fse8d AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow with gcc 9.4

"with C++17 it throws a compilation error" - A compilation failure is expected in C++17 since the overload you use doesn't exist in C++17.

Which line segfaults? A debugger or diagnostic output should be able to tell you.

std::make_shared<char[]>() is C++20, but gcc 9.4 supports c++17 and only c++2a.

@273K so its a bug with gcc 9.4?

This is not a bug. This is a not supported feature. Install gcc-10. error: static assertion failed: make_shared<T[]> not supported

If it's not supported, why does it allow compilation?

@thc Because they made a mistake. It compiles in 9.4 but not in 9.5. I'd use 12.1 or later.

If they made a mistake, it sounds like a bug?

@thc Oh yes. Every compiler comes with bugs. Every C++ compiler I should say. C++ is a nasty language in the sense that it's extremely difficult to get everything right :-)

It appears the bug has since been fixed.  Have you tried using a current GCC?

The question was answered in the comments and I'd just like to summarize in case anyone comes across this obscure issue.

This is a bug in GCC 9.4
std::make_shared of an array is a C++20 feature
It should not be available for  when compiling with c++17, but it is when using GCC 9.4
Possible workarounds: use the normal constructor e.g. std::shared<char>(new char[100]) ... or just use std::vector as the other answer suggested
C++ is hard!


std::shared<char>(new char[100]) would then use delete instead of delete[], which is UB.

as a complement to the full answer of @thc
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    size_t size = 55;
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<char[]>(size);
    std::cout << (static_cast<unsigned int>(ptr[0]) & 0xFF) << " " << (size & 0xFF) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Output:
55 55

Due to the bug, argument of make_shared becomes the initializer of the first char, not a size of array of char

A possible workaround:
struct MyClass {
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>> blockPtr;
    std::vector<char>& block;


    MyClass() : blockPtr(std::make_shared<std::vector<char>>(BLOCKSIZE)), 
                block(*blockPtr.get()) {}

